# Any idea why MSVC returns -1 for mktime?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have the following code:

```
int main() {
    std::tm tm{};
    tm.tm_min = 30;
    tm.tm_hour = 15;
    tm.tm_mday = 1;

    auto tt = std::mktime(&tm);
    std::cout << tt;
}
```

any idea why MSVC returns `-1` for `mktime()`? clang and gcc return value(negative non `-1` value, so it should be valid). I'm using VS2019, and compiler version is 19.27.29111.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/mktime-mktime32-mktime64?view=msvc-160) says "If timeptr references a date before midnight, January 1, 1970, or if the calendar time cannot be represented, _mktime32 returns -1 cast to type time_t." I would assume since 0 < 1970 for the year it doesn't like it.

Comment: Consider using `<chrono>` for this job instead:  `auto tt = 15h + 30min;`  or `auto tt = hours{15} + minutes{30};`

Comment: @HowardHinnant This is just a sample code. I need to parse time from string and do some comparison. So I somehow need to use `std::tm` for `std::get_time()`, unless I want to completely parse time myself.

Comment: Ok.  Here's a [demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PKGvMKH3unreEste) of a free, open-source [preview of C++20](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) that adds parse functionality to `<chrono>`.

Comment: If you're using the very latest MSVC (don't recall the version number), that `date` stuff is actually in `<chrono>` already, so you don't even need date.h.

Comment: @HowardHinnant You mean `std::chrono::parse()` isn't it? Cannot find its support in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support . need to test it for now. Thanks for help anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::mktime()` returns the "time since epoch", which is Jan 1st, 1970. The exact type of `time_t` is  unspecified, but the semantics is the famous Unix-derived "seconds since epoch", that is, Jan 1st, 1970, 0:00 h. The [POSIX standard says](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mktime.html):

> The mktime() function shall convert the broken-down time, expressed as local time, in the structure pointed to by timeptr, into a time since the Epoch value with the same encoding as that of the values returned by time().

And [for time()](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/time.html):

> The time() function shall return the value of time [CX]  in seconds since the Epoch.

The "[CX]" tag indicates that "in seconds since the Epoch" is an extension to the C standard: C leaves the calendar time encoding unspecified (e.g., it could be a floating point type and/or have a different 0 base, although both would be surprising).

In any case, POSIX continues to specify the return value of `mktime()`as

> The mktime() function shall return the specified time since the Epoch encoded as a value of type time_t. **If the time since the Epoch cannot be represented, the function shall return the value (time_t)-1 [...].**

Because you have zero-initialized the structure the year is 0, which means "1900" (the year is specified as a delta to 1900), the date is well before the epoch, and the VC standard library implementers [decided to not accept such inputs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/mktime-mktime32-mktime64?view=msvc-160), in violation of the C and POSIX standards ("If the calendar time **cannot be represented**")

> **If timeptr references a date before midnight, January 1, 1970,** or if the calendar time cannot be represented, _mktime32 [and, apparently, _mktime64; -ps] returns -1 cast to type time_t.

Times before 1970 could simply be encoded as negative values, and all others (gcc, icc, clang) [seem to have done that](https://www.godbolt.org/z/EchTY3e3z). One reason for Microsoft's approach may be that allowing times before the epoch makes it impossible to check the success of the function because -1, like all other negative values, is a possible regular result. Overflows could no longer be distinguished from proper operation. This may become a real [issue in as little as 17 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) on systems using 32 bit counters, so perhaps Microsoft did a risk analysis and decided too much was at stake — programs would silently fail if they could not perform error checks. After all, Microsoft products are used in administrations and slow-moving environments which conceivably will not run 64 bit hardware or software in 2038.

POSIX mandates to set `errno` upon error, but that is an extension.

In any case, if you add `tm.tm_year = 70;`to your code, shifting the point in time after the epoch, it prints the expected positive number.

Comment: I was trying to compare 2 hours only(without date, assuming both same day), so I left everything as zero. but it seems it is not correct to do so. Although I don't see this limit on `std::mktime` reference.

Comment: even the sample in cpp ref here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm does not consider this problem.

Comment: @Afshin Yeah, in Linux it works fine and you can even use negative years to get dates before 1900.

Comment: @Afshin Seems a reasonable thing to do -- gcc 10.2, icc and clang [all convert such a time into negative seconds](https://www.godbolt.org/z/EchTY3e3z).

Comment: Isn't the range of 32 bit time_t restricted to +/- 68 years? I.e. the only reason libstdc++ can represent 1900 is because it uses 64 bit time_t? VC++ may very well be able to represent 1969 using a negative value, and still need to return -1 for 1900

Comment: @MSalters True, 1900 would be out of reach for 32 bit negative values. But VC returns -1 also for 1969, and on recent systems one must flip a switch (_USE_32BIT_TIME_T)  to enforce 32 bit timers anyway.